# OCR solution for legal billing invoices

Tags: microsoft-excel, ocr

I have different kinds of legal billing invoices. I want to digitize them into Excel sheets. Since their layouts are different and there are a lot of them, I can't find a way to deal with them. Can someone provide a practical solution to me?

Comment: I would recommend omnipage, but they'll prolly close this as off topic, so shop around, check out alternativeto.net for alertnatives to omnippage if that's not a good fit.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the omnipage and Abbyy, it seems that they provide the products only. They convert the image to text, but they cannot do some calculation and extraction. Is there any solution about the processing such thing? Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Oh, you're looking for an ECM that has OCR? Not JUST an OCR? I'm not sure if Docuware is what you need, it may be overkill, but check it out. We use it for our invoices.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good, reasonably priced solution that I know off :(

You could try checking out Nuance OmniPage or Abby FlexiCapture (there are desktop editions all the way to $100k enterprise versions). Some time back I had compared the SDKs/OCR quality between them. Not much difference, though I felt Abbyy was a teeny little bit better (Nuance crashed a couple of times, Abbyy did not).

Both OmniPage and FlexiCapture (FineReader) have desktop editions that purport to convert PDFs to editable excel files. From what I learned by tinkering with the free trial versions was that they do create editable excel files, but only for very high quality, clean sources. Both also offer batch processing functionality.

Also I've found scanstore.com to be an amazing resource:

http://www.scanstore.com/Scanning_Software/Forms_Processing/Invoice_Processing/

If you're looking for open source - the best 'engine' is tesseract. You will need to build the whole forms capture bit around it. I've done some thinking around this - and you'd need:

1. Use 'barcodes' or otherwise register invoice types
2. For each type - figure out which parts of the invoice are tables
3. Crop the relevant area - and send it to tesserat/abbyy/nuance
4. Get back something that can be parsed into a table
5. Apply language modelling (surprisingly Abbyy, Nuance do a terrible job here)

Oh and FYI there are a lot of 'BPO' service companies who have real people to do data-entry work. It's not as expensive as you'd think.

Comment: Yes, both the OCR company really need a big charge, and your thought about the invoice processing is very helpful. But that doesn't means I should employ an engineer, right? I think I should find a company which do these things for me. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some free OCR softwares:   CuneiForm, GOCR ,Ocrad, OCRopus,Tesseract. But the result is not so good. 
But you can try FineReader, ExperVision, OmniPage, the result will be better. However, based on my experience, you cannot rely on the pure technology solution. If you do want to control your project cost under a reasonable price. Intergrating the OCR technology and human resource is a good choise.
As far as I know, Expervision can provide both customized OCR tech and BPO service, you can check their web.[Expervision](http://www.expervision.com/)